# pass parameter to action property from view in sencha touch

Tags: button, extjs, properties, sencha-touch-2

I have a **button** inside a view and I have set a **action property** of it so that I can listen to its tap event in controller as follows

view code

```
{
     xtype:'button',
     text:'SKIP',
     action:'skip'      
}
```

controller code

```
onSkipContact:function(){
      console.log('tap');
}
```

now what I want to pass the parameter to **onSkipContact action** something like as follows

```
{
  xtype:'button',
  text:'SKIP',
  action:'skip(data.index)' //i want to pass the index of record to the controller      
}
```

so that I can read in controller as follows

```
onSkipContact:function(index){
 console.log('tap' + index );
}
```

panel containing `cv`

```
Ext.define('ca.view.ContactInfoPanel',{

    extend:'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'contactinfopanel',



    requires: [ 'ca.view.ContactInfo','ca.view.ContactVote'],
    config:{

        layout:'vbox',
        defaults: {
                     margin: '10 10 10 10'
          } ,
        items:[{

            xtype:'contactinfo'

        },{

            xtype:'contactvote', // its a CV
        }]


    },
    initialize:function(){


    this.callParent();

    }



});
```

here is the `contactvote` i.e. `cv`

```
Ext.define("ca.view.ContactVote",{

    extend:'Ext.Container',
    xtype:'contactvote',

    requires:['Ext.Button'],

    config:{


        bottom:0,
        width: '100%',


           defaults: {
                     margin: '10 20 0 0'
          } ,
        items:[{

                        xtype:'button',
                        text:'SKIP',
                        action:'skip',
                        id:'skipbtn'



                }]


    },


    initialize:function(){


    console.log(this.data);
    this.callParent();

    }





});
```

Comment: your only need is to set index to the button from controller and no other component using data.. right ?

Comment: yes, thts wht i wanna do

Comment: see my update in my answer

Comment: did you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

First, store the data you want to pass to the handler method in the button itself. For example:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'SKIP',
    action: 'skip',
    // Give it the name you want, just ensure it won't
    // overlap a property defined by Ext.
    dataIndex: data.index
}
```

Ext event listeners are always passed the event source (in your case the button) as their first argument. So in your handler, you can access your data this way:

```
onSkipContact: function(button) {
    var index = button.index;

    console.log('tap' + index);
}
```

Comment: Lol. SO should issue alerts "someone else is currently writing exactly the same thing as you" ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Set the index in button configuration

```
{
  xtype:'button',
  text:'SKIP',
  action:'skip',   
  index : data.index
}
```

In controller action

```
onSkipContact:function(button){
  // You can get index config like this
  console.log('tap' + button.index );    
}
```

I assumed that your have something like following configuration in controller

```
    refs: {
        skipBtn : 'button[action=skip]'
    },
    control: {
        skipBtn : {
          tap: 'onSkipContact'
        }
    }
```

**Update**

Try

```
 this.getCv().down('button[action=skip]').index = record.data.index;
```

instead of

```
this.getCV().setData(record.data)
```

your button code remain

```
{
  xtype:'button',
  text:'SKIP',
  action:'skip'
}
```

Comment: You too lost some time figuring out what this action option was, didn't you?

Comment: @rixo no, i taken as a property of button object

Comment: @Viswa i am getting `this.data.index` or `data.index` undefine

Comment: @Hunt You mean in view ? and how do you passed the data.

Comment: yean in view , i set the data as follows in controller `getCV().setData(record.data)`

Comment: @Hunt do console.log(record); before setting the data in controller and if it prints object then do console.log(record.data);

Comment: `record.data`is working , but when i try to access it in view `data.index` its saying data is undefined

Comment: @Viswa i just checked again `getCV()` is itself undefined even if its   showing in `console(this)`

Comment: i have solved the `getCV()` issue and is set the `getCV().setData(record.data)` and tried to print `console.log(this.getData())` in `initialize` function but there i am getting `this.getData()` is null

Comment: its `this.data` is undefinded , i think `cv` container is inside a Panel and there i have added `cv` by specifying `xtype` so as `cv` is a sub container its not populating a data , could that be a reason ?

Comment: @Hunt can you post that view ?

Comment: @Hunt you have two option 1) set the data to contactinfopanel and pass it to contactvote. 2) set the data to contactvote as you doing now and get the data in contactvote container (not in contactinfopanel).

Comment: i am following the second option only not setting or getting anything in `contactinfonpane`